# how do I add Kaggle dataset into elasticsearch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch, kaggle

I am new to elasticsearch and I am trying to build a movie search app. For this I plan to get data from kaggle and add to my elasticsearch which I have setup locally at localhost:9200. I see this in the localhost link:

```
name    "bxiIZLL"
cluster_name    "elasticsearch"
cluster_uuid    "zc_JPmw4TQ2G5bvahEF6LQ"
version 
number  "5.6.14"
build_hash  "f310fe9"
build_date  "2018-12-05T21:20:16.416Z"
build_snapshot  false
lucene_version  "6.6.1"
tagline "You Know, for Search"enter code here
```

Now I need to add [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/rounakbanik/the-movies-dataset/activity) data to this server. How can I do it? 
I saw somewhere the curld -XPUT command. I am not sure how that can work with Kaggle.

A follow up question - if I want to publish my app later on, how can I host the elasticsearch ?

Comment: in which format is data from Kaggle?

Comment: I see a CSV format - https://www.kaggle.com/tmdb/tmdb-movie-metadata

Comment: Not the Kaggle dataset, but there is an example of indexing Movielens data to provide recommendations using the Graph API, in the Elastic examples repository: https://github.com/elastic/examples/tree/master/Graph/movie_recommendations. Note that this is using Elasticsearch 5.0, so should work with 5.6.14 that you're using

Comment: Add your sample data structure in question.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/blog/importing-csv-and-log-data-into-elasticsearch-with-file-data-visualizer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to upload a CSV file to elasticsearch:

1. download the file.

   2. use logstash in order to read the file using [file input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html)
   3. modify and transform the data as you need using logstash's [CSV filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html)
   4. output logstash to [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html)

For your follow up question - how can I host Elasticsearch - you can either run it by your own, in AWS EC2 for example, or use a managed service like Elastic cloud or AWS ES. good luck